What does the word "Sheol" mean throughout the Hebrew bible?
The word שְׁאוֹל Sheol appears across the Hebrew bible (Gen 37:35, Isa 38:10, Ps 30:4, Isa 14:9, et. al.) and is usually portrayed as the destination of the dead. It's often used in parallel with בּוֹר (pit) and שַׁחַת (chasm). We can also find references to שַׁעֲרֵי שְׁאוֹל (the gates of Sheol) in Isa 38:10, which gives an impression of more than simply a grave.
Is this word a synonym for קֶבֶר (grave)? Is Sheol a specific place? Does it refer to an afterlife? What is the critical understanding of this word?
Related: What is hell? sheol/hades/prison/lake of fire/outer darkness

The Hebrew word she’ol in the NIV is uniformly translated grave, or pit.  Both man and beast go to she’ol (Ps 49:14).  It never suggests a place of torment nor eternal punishing but rather a place of darkness, just like an ordinary grave or crypt.
In Hebrew two words are often used in parallel and sometimes interchangeably: שְׁאוֹל She'ol (="grave" or "place of the dead") and בּוֹר bowr (="pit").  It is uniformly a place of darkness and unconscious silence.  Here is a sample:

Isa 14:15 - But you are brought down to the realm of the dead [=she'ol], to the depths of the pit [=bowr].
Isa 38:18 - For the grave [=she'ol] cannot praise you, death cannot sing your praise; those who go down to the pit [=bowr] cannot hope for your faithfulness.
Prov 1:12 - let’s swallow them alive, like the grave [=she'ol], and whole, like those who go down to the pit [=bowr];
Num 16:33 - They went down alive into the realm of the dead [=she'ol], with everything they owned; the earth closed over them, and they perished and were gone from the community.

The OT describes the following about she'ol [ie, the grave] at death:

Jacob was to go to she'ol, Gen 37:35, 42:38, 44:29, 31
Korah, Dathan and Abiram went into she'ol alive, Num 16:30, 33
No one praises God in She'ol, Ps 6:5, because it is silent, Ps 31:17
The wicked go into she'ol, Ps 9:17
She'ol is a place of total decay, Ps 49:14
it is possible to be thrown alive into she'ol, Ps 55:15 (presumably to die soon after!)
in She'ol there is neither work, or thought or knowledge or wisdom, Eccl 9:10

All the above is consistent with she'ol being a poetic word for the grave as is done by versions like the NIV.

I would add: Acc. to Ps 18, it is also possible to be caught in Sheol while still alive...and to be rescued by God from its snares. The Hymn of Jonah (Jonah 2) apparently equates the belly of the fish (or at least the "deep") with Sheol.

"caught in Sheol while still alive", just as miners are sometimes caught alive in what will be their grave unless rescue workers can get to them in time. There's no implication for the miners or for Jonah that they would continue to remain alive or conscious in their graves.

But there IS an implication that one can actually be in Sheol (spiritually I presume) and be saved by God though prayer. I also notice this from Ps. 139 that God is present in Sheol.  "If I ascend to heaven, You are there; If I make my bed in Sheol, behold, (L)You are there."

@DanFefferman - heaven vs she'ol is a poetic way of saying God is omnipresent.
